# PHP: warning preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have been having a really hard time debugging this error since the past 2 days...googled for every possible solution bu failed...would be really helpful if anyone could help me out with it:

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wi_class_files\autoMakeLinks.php on line 7
```

The code is:

```
class autoActiveLink {

    function makeActiveLink($originalString){

        $newString = preg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]i/","\\0", $originalString);
        return $newString;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which one is line 7 in your file?  Because the way you posted it, it looks like the `$` in your `return $newString;` line is causing a problem.

Comment: Have you tried escaping all the slashes like `\/`?

Comment: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot your delimiters (at the beginning AND at the end of your mask)

```
class autoActiveLink {  
    function makeActiveLink($originalString) {  
        $newString = preg_replace("#[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]#i","<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $originalString);
        return $newString;
     }
 }
```